# OrderedDict: are values ordered, too?

Tags: python

The [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) documentation describes an `OrderedDict` as a

> a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted

so the order of

```
for k in dict:
  ...

for k in dict.keys():
  ...
```

is predictable.

However, it does not say anything about values. If I only need to iterate over the values as follows, will the results respect the ordering-by-insert as well?

```
for v in dict.values():
  ...
```

A few quick tests here in CPython showed that to be the case, but that could just be coinicidental with the current implementation (I haven't tested any others).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, the lists by `keys()` and `values()` are arranged in corresponding orders in all dicts, [not just in ordered ones](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Prior to Python 3.6, the order was arbitrary for normal dicts, but it was **the same** arbitrary order returned by `keys()`, `values()` and `items()`, provided the dict wasn't modified between calls to those methods.

As of CPython 3.6, dict respects insertion order. Beginning with Python 3.7, it has become a [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict) guarantee.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they are sorted in the same order as the keys are. This is the same with all `dict` implementations.

> Keys and values are iterated over in an arbitrary order which is
>   non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the
>   dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions. If keys, values and
>   items views are iterated over with no intervening modifications to the
>   dictionary, the order of items will directly correspond. This allows
>   the creation of `(value, key)` pairs using `zip()`: `pairs =
>   zip(d.values(), d.keys())`. Another way to create the same list is
>   `pairs = [(v, k) for (k, v) in d.items()]`.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views